# I am trying to construct TF-IDF Matrix in order to compute sentiment score of amazon reviews

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis, feature-extraction

I am trying to construct TF-IDF Matrix in order to compute sentiment score of amazon reviews
I have preprocessed the data, data is a list of all the reviews, where every element in the list is a review

[x2 is a list of reviews (output after applying the lemmatization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Cey.png)

now i need to build a TF-IDF matrix, i am facing error , i am not sure how to feed the data to built TF-IDF Matrix

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False,sublinear_tf=False,norm=None,analyzer='word')
    
txt_fitted = tf.fit(x2)
txt_transformed = txt_fitted.transform(x2)
print("The Text:",x2)
```

packages used : sklearn

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K9Bq.png)

(sorry about the indentation , this is my first post)

Comment: `TfIdfVectorizer` accepts strings or text files, so you should transform `x2` into a Series/list of strings or something along those lines. You're actually working with a list of lists and that's why you're having issues

Comment: Thank you @JuanC for the response, but when i transform list of list to list to strings , how do i differentiate between among reviews? so if i understood to right each review (a string ) will be separated by a comma. am i right?

Comment: So you have a list of lists, where each list is a review, right? now you'll have a list of strings where each string is a review. Something like `' '.join(x2)` should work

Comment: thank you @JuanC i have converted the list  to list of strings and this how it looks like...  

['exactly need perfect replacement',
 'agree review opening small almost bend hook expensive earring try get high end see would buy price send back agree review opening',
 'love go order another pack keep work someone include always lose back earring understand fish hook earring wish tiny bit long new friend',
 'tiny opening two star',
 'okay three star']